# Listen to the VBA events in Excel and trigger a Javascript/typescript function in OfficeJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, vba, office-js, office-addins

I have a requirement to **listen to the Excel's 'Save' button event and call a javascript/typscript function in OfficeJS**.

I tried the following

**In Excel file (.xlsm) I added a new Module and added the following VBA code.**

```
Sub SaveButton_Click()
    ' Perform necessary operations before saving

    ' Call the JavaScript function and receive the value in VBA
    Dim returnValue As String
    returnValue = CallExcelJsFunction("saveButtonClicked")
    
    ' Process the returned value in VBA
    MsgBox "Returned value: " & returnValue
    
    ' Perform additional operations after notifying Office JS
End Sub
Function CallExcelJsFunction(functionName As String) As String
    Dim scriptControl As Object
    Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    
    ' Set the language to JavaScript
    scriptControl.Language = "JScript"
    
    ' Call the JavaScript function and receive the return value
    Dim returnValue As String
    returnValue = scriptControl.Eval(functionName & "()")
    
    ' Return the value to the VBA macro
    CallExcelJsFunction = returnValue
End Function
```

And then **enabled the Microsoft Script Control from Tools--> Referneces --> 'Microsoft Script Control'** , apparently this allows communication between VBA and other scripting languages.

Then I **added a function inside TaskPane.ts of my typescript code**

```
async function saveButtonClicked() {
  // Perform actions or calculations
  var result = "Hello from Office JS";

  // Return the value to the calling code (if necessary)
  return result;
}
```

**This is how my TaskPane.ts looks**

[![TaskPane.ts][1]][1]

I then **created a ActiveXCommand button in the Excel sheet and added the following code to the click event**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Call the SaveButton_Click macro
    SaveButton_Click
End Sub
```

Now when I click the button in Excel, the function in my typescript file should be called and then return the text from the function.

**However I get the following error.**

[![Excel Error][2]][2]

**Can someone help me in finding out the issue? Is it with VBA ? I am not a VBA developer so have no idea on VBA code or errors.**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKBhA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao5qv.png

Comment: Your ScriptControl has no knowledge of your task pane - you can't run a task pane function like that.

Comment: A few related questions here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+call+officejs+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

The Office JavaScript API (`OfficeJS`) doesn't provide anything for that. There is no way to call Office web add-in from your VBA macros (or the opposite).

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.